# What to do in case of theft of passport with visa and residence permit

Tags: visas, passports, security, permits, vienna

I am an Indian student residing in Italy, my girlfriend is also a student from India residing in Vienna, today her wallet containing her passport (with visa) and residence permit were stolen.

We promptly filed a report at the local police station, where the police office told us that the report is enough for travelling to Vienna (she left today).

I printed out the last and front pages of the passport as well as the the visa and attached them to the report, hoping that will be enough for her return trip.

I understand from previous posts that the Embassy at Vienna will issue her a temporary passport.

But I am a bit scared, as she has no other documents with her. Not even the residence permit. How would she go about regenerating everything?

For now we decided that she will go to the local police station in vienna and file another report before proceeding to the embassy for a temporary passport.

But what happens from there?

Comment: I wonder if this might be better on [Expats](http://expatriates.stackexchange.com/), since loosing the residency permit is more of an expats things

Comment: Most of all, do not panic. This is not unusual. Do you have any other (digital) proof of her identity? It does not need to be official. A letter from insurance perhaps? Take that to the embassy. And ask your question on Expats. They (and the people at the embassy) will know more.

Comment: thanks for the response...she had scanned copies of her passport so that with the police documents are her identity atm....

Comment: Keep in mind: NEVER WALK WITH THE ORIGINALS. Preventing a problem is the best way to deal with it.
I always use plastic covered copies of originals. My originals are often deposited in a safe or an embassy. Your bag should be in front of you and across your shoulders. When you sit down someplace, make sure you don't put your belongings on the side of you, but under the table with your leg through the strap. Never sit with your back to the main traffic, always face it.

Comment: This happened to me once (although I'm not Indian) and my embassy was happy with my credit card (it has a small picture of me at the back) as proof of identity, so I'm sure there will be alternative ways of proving her identity. (As Constantine mentioned)

Comment: Be aware that there are no border controls within Europe. You can live your whole life and drive between Italy and Vienna (and all other states in the EU), and never be asked for an ID ever. So, most probably, nothing at all will happen, as nobody will even know that she has no ID.

Comment: @Aganju all other states in the EU?  Try doing that between France and the UK, or Hungary and Croatia, and see how well it works.  In short, I think you mean *all other states in the Schengen area*; even then, Schengen signatories are allowed to institute border checks for certain periods, and some do.